How to retrieve foreign key data of django in jquery and ajax
I am doing CRUD operation in Django with Ajax and jQuery. I have category and product model. I want to fetch category title in product table.  tried and i am unable to get category title. please have a look on my code and provide me the solutions.
this is my model
class Category(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


   

my view code
def MyProduct(request):
        allproducts = Product.objects.values().order_by('-id')
        products = list(allproducts)
        return JsonResponse({"status": "success", "products":products})

this is template with jquery ajax
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        $('#tblDataList tbody').append(
            <tr>your text
                <td class="sn"> ${i+1} </td>
                <td class="title"> ${data[i].title} </td>
                <td class="category">** ${data[i].category.title}** </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

I tried to display category title but it shows undefined.

this is my console data
[
{
"id": 12,
"title": " new data ",
"description": "  test  ",
"category_id": 2,
"quantity": 5,
},
]

in database table category field name is
category_id for product table

ok it is Beverage

it is undefined

what's the database table column name where Beverage is stored? is it the title? or name? or something elses

the column name of table is title

my last attempt : try {{ products.category }} or {{ products.category.title }} or {{category.title }}

actually i am using ajax and jquery to append list of data. above code displays category title in django but with ajax call it shows undefined.  my code is  ${data[i].category} 

sorry I am unable to help now. I hope this JsonResponse({"status": "success", "products":products}) is coming in your Ajax response data which you are trying to use. And previously you showed that console.log(data) doesn't have a category name or title. So I doubt that JsonResponse({"status": "success", "products":products}) have category related data
